# Group dataframe by multiple variables in R

Tags: r, split, dplyr, sample

I have a dataframe containing 5713 rows and 7 columns. Many of the rows are duplicates. I need to create groups of 5 by "gender" and "size" while ensuring the "item" column does not contain duplicates and the "type" column only contains a maximum of 1 "Fleece". I have tried sample, split, group_by, sample_n, but can't seem to figure out how to include all the variables.

Here is a sample of the dataframe:

```
                  SKU          UPC   type rating size gender  item
1  M3MEN-SU15-BLU-XXL 628012010215    Tee      5  XXL      M M3MEN
2  M3MEN-SU15-GRY-XXL 628012010314    Tee      5  XXL      M M3MEN
3   M3MEN-SU15-GRY-XL 628012010316   Tank      5   XL      M M3MEN
4          MAMA-CHA-S *MAMA-CHA-S*   Tank      5    S      M  MAMA
5          MAMA-CHA-S *MAMA-CHA-S*    Tee      5    S      M  MAMA
6          MBAN-CHA-M *MBAN-CHA-M* Fleece      3    M      W  MBAN
7          WAZA-CHA-L *WAZA-CHA-L* Fleece      3    L      M  WAZA
8          MBAN-CHA-M *MBAN-CHA-M* Fleece      3    M      W  MBAN
9          MBAN-CHA-M *MBAN-CHA-M* Fleece      3    M      M  MBAN
10         MCON-CHA-M *MCON-CHA-M* Fleece      3    M      M  MCON
```

Ideally I would like to create a new column that creates a unique ID for each group of 5.

For example:

```
                  SKU          UPC   type rating size gender  item  id
1    M3MEN-SU15-BLU-S 628012010215    Tee      5    S      M M3MEN   1
2          MAMA-CHA-S *MAMA-CHA-S*   Tank      5    S      M  MAMA   1
3          MBAN-CHA-S *MBAN-CHA-S*   Tank      3    S      M  MBAN   1
4          MAZA-CHA-S *MAZA-CHA-S*    Tee      3    S      M  MAZA   1
5          MCON-CHA-S *MCON-CHA-S* Fleece      3    S      M  MCON   1  
6    W3MEN-SU15-BLU-M 428012010215    Tee      2    M      W W3WOM   2
7          WAMA-CHA-M *WAMA-CHA-M*   Tank      4    M      W  MAMA   2
8          WBAN-CHA-M *WBAN-CHA-M*   Tank      5    M      W  MBAN   2
9          WAZA-CHA-M *WAZA-CHA-M*    Tee      1    M      W  MAZA   2
10         WCON-CHA-M *WCON-CHA-M* Fleece      3    M      W  MCON   2
```

I have been struggling with this for awhile now. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you show the code you've tried? That would help get across what you're trying to do. Including a reproducible example with `dput(head(yourdata, 20))` would also help.

Comment: I've tried creating samples of the groups (by gender and size) but it doesn't solve the problem of unique "item" or "type" containing more than 1 instance of fleece. `df <- df %>% group_by(gender, size) %>% sample_n(size = 5)`

Comment: When you said >need to create groups of 5 by "gender" and "size"   Is there any particular reason you say 5 , instead of just saying I need to create groups of the same gender-and-size eg Male, Small first. Then show Male, Medium. Then show Male, Large. Then show Female, Small, and so on. Just want to know if the 5 is some kind of additional requirement or just something you noticed that there can only be 5 variations as far as you know, of each gender + size group.

Comment: @user454038 I need groups of 5 because I'm trying to create product bundles of 5 items. Each item needs to be different in the bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding duplicates of `item` within a group is straightforward with the `distinct` function:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(gender, size) %>%
  distinct(item)
```

Ensuring there is not more than one "Fleece" is a bit trickier, but doable with `filter` and `cumsum`. This removes all but the first Fleece (within each group).

```
  filter(!(type == "Fleece" & cumsum(type == "Fleece") > 1))
```

Then you can do `sample_n` as you attempted originally:

```
  sample_n(5)
```

In total, your code is:

```
df <- df %>%
  group_by(gender, size) %>%
  distinct(item) %>%
  filter(cumsum(type == "Fleece") <= 1) %>%
  sample_n(5)
```